# Change position of gameobjects with slider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 4 gameobject in my game and I want to change X and Y values of these objects with slider. But I don't know how will I do that. I need to help.

Now, I use button to play animation with the code below but I want to change gameobject positions with slider.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playbut : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject anim;
public GameObject anim1;
public GameObject anim2;
public GameObject scrool;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
public void OnClick(){
    anim.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("div");
    anim1.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("div1");
    StartCoroutine(WaitandPrint(2));
    anim2.GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("div2");
}


private IEnumerator WaitandPrint(float waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

    scrool.SetActive (true);
}
```

}

Here is what I want :

All of position of the gameobjects is X : -2.6 Y : -2.09 but when I slide the slider the position of the gameobjects should be like that :

Gameobject 1 = X:2.5 Y:-0.03

Gameobject 2 = X:-5.74 Y:0.09

Gameobject 3 = X:-2.18 Y:2.48

Gameobject 4 = X:-2.6 Y:-2.09

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're asking. Do you need to know how to setup a full scene or are you struggling with something specific?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some more details and explain exactly what you are trying to achieve. Currently it is hard to tell what you are actually asking...

Comment: Hello, sorry for unclear question. I want to make animation with slider. When I slide the slider, gameobjects should change position on X and Y position. So, I want to learn how do I move gameobject with slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several ways to do so, depending on your needs.

EDIT: After the additional details you gave, what I understand is that you have only one slider for all your gameObjects. You want to set the position of each gameObject between two points according to the position of the slider. Like a Linear Interpolation.

[image: Lerp]

If so :

1. Add the following script to the object you want (an empty gameObject / the slider).
2. Set the `Size` property to `4` to handle your 4 objects. It will create an array with 4 entries.
3. For each element

   1. Drag & drop the gameObject to move into the `Transform` field
   2. Specify the "Start position" (`PositionA`), which is the position of the object when the slider value is equal to `0`
   3. Specify the "End position" (`PositionB`), which is the position of the object when the slider value is equal to `1`
   4. Change the `Points Color` so that the color of the gizmo in the Scene view will make it easier to identify
4. Make sure the slider value foes from `0` to `1`, and that the `SetPosition` is the callback of the `onValueChanged` event.
5. Add a new entry in the `On Value Changed` event of the slider (**only one**). Drag & drop the gameObject holding the script, and choose the `SetPosition (dynamic float)` function of the component
6. Run the game, and move the slider to see each object go from their `PositionA` to `PositionB`.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public struct TransformBetweenPoints // could not find an appropriate name....
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 positionA;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 positionB;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform transform;

    public void SetPosition( float t )
    {
        if( transform != null )
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp( positionA, positionB, t );
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [SerializeField]
    private Color pointsColor;
    public void DrawGizmos()
    {
        Color gizmosColor = Gizmos.color;
        if ( pointsColor.a <= Mathf.Epsilon ) pointsColor.a = 1;

        if( transform != null )
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawRay( transform.position, Vector3.right );
            Gizmos.color = Color.green;
            Gizmos.DrawRay( transform.position, Vector3.up );
            Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
            Gizmos.DrawRay( transform.position, Vector3.forward );
            Gizmos.color = pointsColor;
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere( transform.position, 0.2f );
        }

        Gizmos.color = pointsColor;
        Gizmos.DrawLine( positionA - Vector3.right, positionA + Vector3.right );
        Gizmos.DrawLine( positionB - Vector3.right, positionB + Vector3.right );
        Gizmos.DrawLine( positionA - Vector3.up, positionA + Vector3.up );
        Gizmos.DrawLine( positionB - Vector3.up, positionB + Vector3.up );
        Gizmos.DrawLine( positionA - Vector3.forward, positionA + Vector3.forward );
        Gizmos.DrawLine( positionB - Vector3.forward, positionB + Vector3.forward );
        Gizmos.color = gizmosColor;
    }
#endif
}

public class PositionHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TransformBetweenPoints[] transforms;

    public void SetPosition( float value )
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < transforms.Length ; ++i )
            transforms[i].SetPosition( value );
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; transforms != null && i < transforms.Length ; ++i )
            transforms[i].DrawGizmos();
    }
#endif
}
```

---

If you have 2 sliders for each object (a total of 8 sliders for your 4 objects), then, you could attach the following script to each object to move and [call the appropriate function in the `onValueChanged` of the slider](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-slider). You will have to change the range of the slider to move the object according to your needs.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PositionHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 position;

    public void SetPositionX( float value )
    {
        position = transform.position;
        position.x = value ;
        transform.position = position;
    }

    public void SetPositionY( float value )
    {
        position = transform.position;
        position.y = value ;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

---

If you have only 2 sliders for all your objects, you will need the following script you can attach to an empty gameObject, or the panel containing the 2 sliders + a way to change the `Target` property (through another script, or the same script, depending on what you want to do). Again, you will have to specify the `SetPosition` callbacks in the `onValueChange` events.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PositionSlider : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform target;
    private Vector3 position;

    public Transform Target
    {
        get { return target ; }
        set { target = value ; }
    }

    public void SetPositionX( float value )
    {
        if( Target == null )
        {
            Debug.LogError("The target is null, can't set its position!");
            return;
        }
        position = Target.position;
        position.x = value ;
        Target.position = position;
    }

    public void SetPositionY( float value )
    {
        if( Target == null )
        {
            Debug.LogError("The target is null, can't set its position!");
            return;
        }
        position = Target.position;
        position.y = value ;
        Target.position = position;
    }
}
```

---

Please, edit your question and add details about your problem for adequate help.

Comment: Hello. I want to use just 1 slider. Is it possible ?

Comment: In summary, I want to change of 4 gameobjects position with just one slider. For example; the position of the first gameobject is X: -2 Y: -2.5 and the position of the second object is X: -5 Y:-3 but when I slide the slider, the position of the first object should be X:-4 Y:-2 and the position of the second one should be X:-6 Y:-4. This is the thing what I need to do

Comment: @BatuhanTaştekin I've edited my answer, tell me if I understood your problem correctly, and if the code I've added fit your needs.

Comment: I added empty slider and I already have 4 gameobject. Which one (slider or gameobject) should I attach this script ?

Comment: As I have indicated, the script must be attached to an empty gameObject in your scene, or the slider itself. Then, you will have to populate the `Transforms` array in the inspector and drag&drop the 4 objects into the appropriate fields + changing vector positions.

Comment: I added your script to my empty slider. But I see just size part under Transforms. Here you can see the slider details [Slider](http://prntscr.com/npr3q2)

Comment: Yes, it's an array.... So set the size to 4 (for 4 objects) and fill the array...

Comment: I started to add the final position of gameobjects to Position A but I don't understand what is Position B. And how can I assign this script with the gameobjects ?

Comment: `PositionA` is the position of the gameObjects when the slider value is 0 (start position). `PositionB` is the position of the gameObjects when the slider value is 1. The `Transform` property below each `PositionA` & `PositionB` fields are the objects to move (your 4 objects)

Comment: I did like that but didn't work. http://prntscr.com/npv5kt Also do you have a chance to connect my computer via TeamViewer

Comment: It seems you haven't used a lot Unity... I've edited my answer and added details explanations.

Comment: Still don't work. You text "Drag & drop the gameObject holding the script, and choose the SetPosition (dynamic float) function of the component" the script in the slider. I dragged and dropped slider to On Value Changed part. You can see http://prntscr.com/npwmki

Comment: The callback seems to be correctly added. Have you tried to run the scene? What does not work?

Comment: I slide the slider but nothing changed

Comment: Everything works perfectly fine here. Add `Debug.LogFormat("Moving transform '{0}' between {1} and {2} (value of t = {3})", transform.name, PositionA, PositionB, t )` inside the condition, in the `SetPosition` function of the struct (dont forget to add braces around the `Debug.LogFormat` and `transform.position`

Comment: Hi, didn't work but I completed the project. I archived your code. Thanks a lot for your helps !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a screen space canvas, and create a new Slider UI element as a child of that canvas.

If you're confused on how to do that, search online for a Unity uGUI tutorial.

Then you will want to write a script to define a method to call when the Slider's value is changed; this can be set via the inspector on the Slider.

That script should have a reference to the Transform of the game object it's supposed to move, and the method it calls when the Slider value is changed should change the position member of the Transform to do so.

If you're confused on how to do that, search online for a Unity scripting tutorial.